# R/Excel: Export a column with numbers in correct format to excel

Tags: r, excel

Hi i've a data frame from dicember. I have a column with costs (of class num  within R).

When exporting to excel, i have to put the correct format (eg. or number of money). But the problem is that in excel i see: 170997.6 - When it should be: 17,099.76.

When i apply formatting "Coin (Moneda in spanish)", it turns out: 170,997.60 (a total wrong number).

Is there a way to export this numbers in the correct format from R? Or how to do this correctly within Excel?

```
        date    Mes          Goal   Fuentes GoalsCompletions    ad.cost
1   2014-12-01  diciembre    Vida   Directo       0              0.00
2   2014-12-01  diciembre    Vida   Campa�as      0             0.00
3   2014-12-01  diciembre    Vida   Referencias   1              0.00
4   2014-12-01  diciembre    Vida   SEO           1              0.00
5   2014-12-01  diciembre    Vida   Email         0              0.00
6   2014-12-01  diciembre    Vida   RRSS          3              48.39
7   2014-12-01  diciembre    Vida   Adwords       3              726.70
8   2014-12-02  diciembre    Vida   Directo       0              0.00
9   2014-12-02  diciembre    Vida   Campa�as      2             36.79
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the number correct in R? Check the data in R first, then export as a `.csv`.

Comment: @User7598, the data is correct. The problem is when formating. It should be just 2 numbers before the "," but in excel i see 3 numbers before the ",". I'm wondering if its something you should do within R, or in Excel itself.

Comment: If the data is right in R and is correct if you open using a text editor, sounds like a problem with excel.

Comment: Formatting as currency should work. If not, you can create a custom format such as `##,##0` and this should work.

Comment: My guess is that you have your installation of Excel set up so that it uses `","` as the decimal separator, which is a continental European standard.

Comment: @I've checked and says: "," for thousends and "." for decimals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the following worked (in R):

**Data**

(I added a few different numbers for the illustration)

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text='        date    Mes          Goal   Fuentes GoalsCompletions    ad.cost
1   2014-12-01  diciembre    Vida   Directo       0              0.00
2   2014-12-01  diciembre    Vida   Campanas      0             0.00
3   2014-12-01  diciembre    Vida   Referencias   1              17099.76
4   2014-12-01  diciembre    Vida   SEO           1              1233.45
5   2014-12-01  diciembre    Vida   Email         0              1000.00
6   2014-12-01  diciembre    Vida   RRSS          3              48.39
7   2014-12-01  diciembre    Vida   Adwords       3              726.70
8   2014-12-02  diciembre    Vida   Directo       0              0.00
9   2014-12-02  diciembre    Vida   Campanas      2             36.79')

#formatting with prettyNum to show as you want
df$ad.cost <- prettyNum(df$ad.cost, big.mark=',', scientific=F)

#write xlsx with the write.xlsx function of the xlsx package
library(xlsx)
write.xlsx(df, 'test.xlsx')
```

The output is as you want it to be (including the number you quoted in your question).

(The column in excel will be a character, which according to what you are trying to do you might need to convert back to numeric)

[image]

Comment: i conver it back with: `"df$ad.cost <- as.numeric(prettyNum(df$ad.cost, big.mark=',', scientific=F))`  Right?

Comment: The output of the `prettyNum` function is a character string from which I suppose you need to first remove the commas with `gsub` and then use `as.numeric` to convert it back to numeric (but that's if you work in R). You need to export it as character though so that the output in excel will be correct. If you export it as numeric then you will probably face the same problem again.

Comment: Ok, ill try that. I need to peform math operations with this columns. Thanks, LyzandeR.

Comment: No problem :) happy to help :). You can either convert it back to numeric in excel by formatting the cells which will be easy I suppose or do the math in r and then export in the excel as character (and convert back in numbers if you want to).