# R transforms large numbers to scientific format in Excel while using write_xlsx

Tags: r, excel, shiny

I have gone through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397664/force-r-not-to-use-exponential-notation-e-g-e10) and have set `options(scipen=999)` and that solves all problems related to converting large numbers to scientific format in R/R Environment. But while using write_xlsx in Shiny, when I open the file downloaded in Excel I see that the large numbers get converted to scientific format.

```
100000000000 becomes 1e+11
200000000000 becomes 2e+11
```

How can I stop this from happening?
Providing part of the server code.

```
    output$dl_bulk <-
       
      downloadHandler(
      filename = "Data.xlsx",
      content = function(file){
        write_xlsx(list("PP" = df_p(), "PM" = df_m(), "PR" = df_r(), "PS" = df_s()), path = file)
      }
      )
```

Comment: What about modifying the Excel file directly by changing the column formats?

Comment: That is obviously a solution but I want to do it from within R.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28571317/r-excel-export-a-column-with-numbers-in-correct-format-to-excel) help?

Comment: No, not really.